# Redmine plugin install (RedmineCRM Finance) results in 503

Tags: plugins, installation, redmine, redmine-plugins

So my problem is that for some some reason installation of some plugins kills my bitnami redmine "permanently" (thin_redmine and thin_redmine2 stops after like 5 seconds).

The plugin which most recently did this is Finance Plugin from RedmineCRM. Version should be okay.
http://www.redmine.org/plugins/finance

Method I used (note that I added :migrate in the second line compared to their website (Is this the problem?)):

```
bundle install --without development test
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=redmine_finance RAILS_ENV=production
```

Am I missing or wrongly doing something? (Please note that I'm not really an expert in this field so I mainly go after how to-s.)

Are there anymore prerequirements for this (besides a very basic working redmine) e.g. I did not set up e-mail notifications, can stuff like this cause the problem?

Comment: do you see error in logs? is it possible to look at the plugin code without downloading it (github?!)? Maybe plugin README has some important notes.

Comment: 'ActiveRecord::Migration.rename_table :operation_types, :operation_categories
ActiveRecord::Migration.rename_column :operations, :type_id, :category_id" '

This is the content of the plugin readme

Comment: well, your Redmine can't start - smth breaks it. You should find out what is the problem. You can do it by analyzing logs or try to run in console `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` - I am sure you will get an error - fix it or post in the question in order to get help.

Comment: The gemfile freeze was the problem. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfreez the gemfile. It solved the problem.